# How efficiently query for groups of data that are next to each other in timeline

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data with column zone and starttime.
I want to query for n latest groups of data where group is defined as records with the same zones without other zones in between sorted by starttime. 
[image: Sample]

In this example the n is 4. First group has 2 A's then 2 B's, then again single A and then 3 C's.

I have a query that performs this task correctly:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ffbee/1
However this query is probably not efficient for large tables because it first selects all data and only later get's what it needs.
I'm aware that this is probably possible to write using procedure but I wonder if I can achieve it using only sql in declarative way.

UPDATE

I have benchmarked original query, @Sentinel query and application solution that fetches 20 results at a time and checks if required number of groups has been achieved. The n is 4. The group sizes are randomly between 10 and 20. There are 4 zones.
All solutions:
[image: All solutions]
Sentinel query and application solution:
[image: Sentinel query and application solution]

Sentinel's query is optimal. It has constant complexity and is faster than app query. Thanks :)

Source code of the benchmark tool if anyone is interested: https://gitlab.com/virtual92/groups-of-data-timeline-sql-benchmark
Graph source: https://plot.ly/~Vistritium/14/

Comment: Why is the record with encid=9 *not* part of this group? Should it be the start of a new group?

Comment: Yes, encid=9 is start of 5th group as it's zone is different than previous record's zone.

Comment: Oops, now I see: you have the time running backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment on the efficiency of this code in postgresql, but it does avoid the self joins you're using in your sample and uses fewer select statements:

```
with t1 as (
select e.*
     -- Detect the zones leading edges
     , case when zone = lag(zone) over (order by starttime desc)
            then 0 -- Same zone as previous 
            else 1 -- Found a leading edge
       end edge
  from encounter e
), t2 as (
select t1.*
     -- Turn the edges into groups
     , sum(edge) over (order by starttime desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) grp
  from t1
)
select * from t2
where grp <= 4;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how much db engines can optimize it. But in comparison, the imperative way would be take records one by one, join to groups and stop when enough groups are achieved. This imperative solution would be super fast no matter table size (if starttime is indexed). I wonder what is complexity of your solution. Will it increase noticeably if the table is big?

Comment: I added my query to yours on your fiddle, and prepended each query with explain analyze. My query had fewer resource requirements.  to answer your question of scaling I changed the fiddle to have more records (100k): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/211ac/7 Your query failed to run outright with the analyze qualifier but mine processes fine.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Your solution is optimal. :)